# ko.utils.stringStartsWith not working

Tags: knockout.js

Hi all I have the following code in ko

```
<!-- ko if: ko.utils.stringStartsWith($root.currency(), INR) -->
```

but even though when I am getting the data as INR it is not getting validated. So can some one help me

Comment: Is `INR` actually a variable etc, or should it be inside quotes?

Comment: `James` Changes but didn't worked

Comment: Anything being logged in your browser console?

Comment: Yeah `Error in "if" binding: Object doesn't support property or method 'stringStartsWith' [object Comment]`

Comment: `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` was removed  https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/401 use indexOf instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [`ko.utils.stringStartsWith`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/401) was never meant to be used outside of the knockout internals.  You can either implement it as per a post on that link:

```
var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {          
    string = string || "";
    if (startsWith.length > string.length)
        return false;
    return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
};
```

Or perhaps switch to using `indexOf` instead:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.currency().indexOf("INR") === 0 -->
```